# problem with JsonStore and JsonReader

Tags: extjs, jsonreader

In my ExtJS application I use EditorGridPanel to show data from server.

```
var applicationsGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    region: 'west',
    layout: 'fit',
    title: '<img src="../../Content/img/app.png" />  Приложения',
    collapsible: true,
    margins: '0 0 5 5',
    split: true,
    width: '30%',
    listeners: { 'viewready': { fn: function() { applicationsGridStatusBar.setText('Приложений: ' + applicationsStore.getTotalCount()); } } },
    store: applicationsStore,
    loadMask: { msg: 'Загрузка...' },
    sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        singleSelect: true,
        listeners: { 'rowselect': { fn: applicationsGrid_onRowSelect} }
    }),
    viewConfig: { forceFit: true },
    tbar: [{
        icon: '../../Content/img/add.gif',
        text: 'Добавить'
    }, '-', {
        icon: '../../Content/img/delete.gif',
        text: 'Удалить'
    }, '-'],
    bbar: applicationsGridStatusBar,
    columns: [{
        header: 'Приложения',
        dataIndex: 'ApplicationName',
        tooltip: 'Наименование приложения',
        sortable: true,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }, {
        header: '<img src="../../Content/img/user.png" />',
        dataIndex: 'UsersCount',
        align: 'center',
        fixed: true,
        width: 50,
        tooltip: 'Количество пользователей приложения',
        sortable: true
    }, {
        header: '<img src="../../Content/img/role.gif" />',
        dataIndex: 'RolesCount',
        align: 'center',
        fixed: true,
        width: 50,
        tooltip: 'Количество ролей приложения',
        sortable: true}]
    });
```

When I use JsonStore without reader it works, but when I try to update any field it uses my 'create' url instead of 'update'.

```
var applicationsStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    root: 'applications',
    totalProperty: 'total',
    idProperty: 'ApplicationId',
    messageProperty: 'message',
    fields: [{ name: 'ApplicationId' }, { name: 'ApplicationName', allowBlank: false }, { name: 'UsersCount', allowBlank: false }, { name: 'RolesCount', allowBlank: false}],
    id: 'app1234',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        api: {
            create: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist1',
            read: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist',
            update: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist2',
            destroy: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist3'
        }
    }),        
    autoSave: true,
    autoLoad: true,
    writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
        encode: false,
        listful: false,
        writeAllFields: false
    })
});
```

I believe that the problem is that I don't use reader, but when I use JsonReader grid stops showing any data at all.

```
var applicationReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'applications',
    totalProperty: 'total',
    idProperty: 'ApplicationId',
    messageProperty: 'message',
    fields: [{ name: 'ApplicationId' }, { name: 'ApplicationName', allowBlank: false }, { name: 'UsersCount', allowBlank: false }, { name: 'RolesCount', allowBlank: false}]
});

var applicationsStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    id: 'app1234',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        api: {
            create: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist1',
            read: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist',
            update: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist2',
            destroy: '/api/applications/getapplicationslist3'
        }
    }),
    reader: applicationReader,
    autoSave: true,
    autoLoad: true,
    writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
        encode: false,
        listful: false,
        writeAllFields: false
    })
});
```

So, does anyone know what the problem might be and how to solve it. The data returned from my server is Json-formated and seams to be ok

```
{"message":"test","total":2,"applications":[{"ApplicationId":"f82dc920-17e7-45b5-98ab-03416fdf52b2","ApplicationName":"Archivist","UsersCount":6,"RolesCount":3},{"ApplicationId":"054e2e78-e15f-4609-a9b2-81c04aa570c8","ApplicationName":"Test","UsersCount":1,"RolesCount":0}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've managed to know the Store 'id' config option is depricated.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.. I solved it establishing Success Property in the json store and returning success true in the response from my create Method.. here is my code. Hope it helps

```
var EStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore
                ({
                   api: { read: 'getAssignedJobs',
                        create: 'createAssignedJobs',
                        update: 'updateAssignedJobs',
                        destroy: 'destroyAssignedJobs'},
                    root: 'jobData',
                    idProperty: 'Id',
                    autoSave: false,
                    autoLoad: true,
                    batch: true,
                    successProperty: 'success',
                    writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({ encode: true, writeAllFields: true }),
                    fields: [
                        { name: 'Id', type: 'int', mapping: 'Id' },
                        { name: 'ResourceId', type: 'int', mapping: 'fitter_id' },
                        { name: 'StartDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s" },
                        { name: 'EndDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s" },
                        { name: 'status', type: 'int' },
                        { name: 'job_id', type: 'int' }
                                ]
                });
```

and this is my Create method from Server Side..

```
public JsonResult createAssignedJobs(string jobData)
    {
        var Jsondata = (JobfitterToScheduler)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<JobfitterToScheduler>(jobData);
        JobToFitterRepo jobtofitter = new JobToFitterRepo();
        if (Jsondata != null)
        {
            jobtofitter.insertJobToFitter(13, Jsondata.fitter_id, 0, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
            return this.Json(new { success = true, jobData = Jsondata });
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for Ext.data.Api I would say that the verbs are screwed up:

`restActions : {
            create  : 'POST',
            read    : 'GET',
            update  : 'PUT',
            destroy : 'DELETE'
        },`

For me the create should be a PUT and the update should be a POST. But I guess the Sencha guys have a different idea.
Btw, the source is taken from Ext 3.3.1

I guess you could override the restActions object to work as you would expect:

```
Ext.data.Api.restActions = {
create  : 'PUT',
read    : 'GET',
update  : 'POST',
destroy : 'DELETE' };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the JsonStore keys off the record id on whether to do a POST vs PUT. So if the id is non-user generated the it will issue a POST, and a PUT otherwise. I am referring to record.id not record.data.id.

Comment: As I've already told the 'id' option is no more, so one should use 'storeId' instead.
Also the problem has nothing with "POST vs PUT". The store isn't even restful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first part (my stores make the correct calls with similar code) but I can shed light on the 2nd part of your question.

Ext.data.JsonStore does **NOT** accept a reader object - it only takes fields and always makes its own reader, as you can see from the source

```
Ext.data.JsonStore = Ext.extend(Ext.data.Store, {
    constructor: function(config){
        Ext.data.JsonStore.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply(config, {
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader(config)
        }));
    }
});
```

and is confirmed as being "as per docs" in Ext 2.x

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?57189-2.x-Closed-Bug-in-Ext.data.JsonStore-cconstructor

So if you supply your own reader you must, in this case, make an Ext.data.Store instead (this caught me out too)